Announcing an election for 2024
Summary: Freelancing Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for an election on September 17th, 2024 to bring in  more moderators.
For full details of the process, see the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange. The timeline:

Starting on September 24th, 2024, users can nominate themselves. Users can also ask questions on Meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the discussion and election tags.)

On October 1st, 2024, if there are 3 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 3 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to remove a nomination.)

If there are still fewer than 3 candidates at the end of the nomination period even after it is extended, the election will be considered a failure, and the site will be shut down.


If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on Meta on October 9th, 2024 (or October 16th, 2024, if we need to extend the nomination period).



Freelancing's past elections
Freelancing is in need of additional moderators. Currently, only one moderator is keeping tabs on the site. We typically like to have at least two mods on every site but prefer three. Unfortunately, the past three elections has been cancelled due to lack of participation. If we are unable to get at least two more mods on the site it might be time to have a conversation on the future of freelancing and whether it still has enough activity and interest to keep the site functioning or if it might be time to consider migrating its content elsewhere or archiving the site entirely
If you have any questions about the process or moderating in general, please post them in an answer here.

I was unable to participate in the election due to insufficient reputation to nominate myself. I wrote one answer in hope of receiving a few votes, without being disqualified due to the same few people voting on all my answers; as happened to someone else last election. No additional rep was forthcoming. I have experience moderating with very low reputation and believe I've done well these past couple of months where I moderate; and on SE the past decade in general. If Canadian Luke needs a vacation and you need a moderator I'm available.
